# Como incluir codigo php dentro do DELIMITER?

Tags: php

Estou precisando de uma ajuda, gostaria de incluir um código dentro do DELIMETER, mas não estou conseguindo, alguém consegue me ajudar ou propor outra alternativa. A função abaixo mostra toda a quantidade que tenho em estoque, uma forma do cliente escolher a quantidade no checkout!

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
$product = <<<DELIMETER
 <a class="btn btn-default">
 <select id ="quantidade" name="quantidade"> <?PHP for ($i = 0; $i <=$row['produto_quantidade']; $i++) echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
 ?>  </select> </a>
DELIMETER;
```

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Seu "delimiter" é uma string [`heredoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Você quer colocar um select com todas as options dentro dele? É isso?

Comment: Heredoc se comporta como uma string qualquer, não há como executar um código PHP dentro dele. Você precisa trabalhar com concatenação de strings.

Answer (score 2):

[`heredoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) é uma string multilinha, você deve concatenar os resultados e adicioná-los da seguinte forma:

```
$options = "";

for ($i = 0; $i <=10; $i++) {
    $options .= "<option value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
}

$product = <<<DELIMETER
 <a class="btn btn-default">
 <select id ="quantidade" name="quantidade"> {$options}  </select> </a>
DELIMETER;

var_dump($product);
```

Saída:

```
string(400) " <a class="btn btn-default">
 <select id ="quantidade" name="quantidade"> <option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option><option value='8'>8</option><option value='9'>9</option><option value='10'>10</option>  </select> </a>"
```

Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/5qAdX8)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Marcelo!